# XSLT transformation adds an unexpected namespace to the result

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to transform XML to another XML.

But the result XML has `xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` as an attribute, why do i see this attribute and what can I do to avoid this attribute?

Comment: Could you show us your scource Xml, Xslt and Xml result?

Comment: This is happening because you haven't shown us your code. It will continue happening until you show the code and somebody finds the reason and then you correct it. Please, edit the question and add the missing important information.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several reasons, perhaps your stylesheet has the `xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration as it needs it to select or match nodes. That way the declaration might be in scope for result elements and you would need to add `exclude-result-prefixes="n1"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` respectively `xsl:transform` element to avoid the declaration appearing in the result document.

Or the namespace declaration is copied from the input to the output. We really need to see details of your input XML, XSLT, wanted XML result and current XML result to help in that case.

Comment: the later case is true, it is being copied from my source XML to result XML, how can I avoid copying that namespace into my result document.

Comment: If you use XSLT 2.0 then `xsl:copy-of` and `xsl:copy` provide an attribute `copy-namespaces="no"`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copying. If you use XSLT 1.0 then you need to make sure you use `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">...</xsl:element>` instead of `<xsl:copy>...</xsl:copy>` to avoid copying any in scope namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're working in "n1" XML namespace. Use `exclude-result-prefixes="n1"` as the attribute of `<xsl:transform>`.

Comment: this did not work, any other idea?

Comment: it is being copied from my source XML to result XML, how can I avoid copying that namespace into my result document